# Partizip 1 vs Partizip 2 im Partizipialattribut

Tags: verb, past-participle, participle

I think that the sentence

> Das Töten von Tauben ist allerdings eine Maßnahme, die nicht zu gestatten ist

can be reformulated with an extended participle as

> Das Töten von Tauben ist allerdings eine nicht zu **gestattete** Maßnahme.

However my grammar books says the correct answer is

> Das Töten von Tauben ist allerdings eine nicht zu **gestattende** Maßnahme.

I cannot understand why the active version would be used. To my mind the form 'gestattete' should be correct, because  Maßnahme is not an agent. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Using *Partizip II* would be correct if *zu* is omitted:

> Das Töten von Tauben ist allerdings eine nicht gestattete Maßnahme.

The *Partizip II* cannot be used with *zu* in this kind of sentence. This combination with *zu* only works with the infinitive and the *Partizip I*. This combination is used predicatively with the infinitive and attributively with *Partizip I*. The combination of *zu* and *Partizip I* is sometimes called gerundive (Gerundivum in German), following languages like Latin where a distinct verbal form with this name exists.

Despite *Partizip I* having active meaning if used on its own, the combination with *zu* has passive meaning. It expresses necessity or - in the case of negation - impossibility. Becauseof this, *Das Töten von Tauben ist allerdings eine nicht zu gestattende Maßnahme* is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the relative clause

> 1) (eine Maßnahme) die nicht zu gestatten ist

*die* (referring to *Maßnahme*) is the subject, just as in:

> 2) (eine Maßnahme) die nicht gestattet wurde

Both relative clauses are passive in the sense that the subject corresponds to the logical object of *gestatten*, i.e. the thing being permitted.

Used attributively, these become

> 1') die nicht zu gestattende Maßnahme
> 2') die nicht gestattete Maßnahme

with the noun corresponding to the subject of the relative clause (and again, the logical object of *gestatten*). The active variants, with the subject of the relative clause and the noun in the attributive construction corresponding to the logical subject of *gestatten*, are:

> 3) (eine Behörde) die etwas gestattet
> 3') die gestattende Behörde

Looking at 1')–3'), it is evident that German has three types of attributive infinitives: the *zu*-participle or gerundive *zu gestattend*, the past participle *gestattet* and the present participle *gestattend*‚ with the former two being passive. A combination of *zu* with the past participle (**zu gestattet*) does not exist.

Regarding the terminology, see Kirsi Pakkanen-Kilpiä, "Zum Wesen des deutsches Gerundivs – Eine Korpuslinguistische Analyse", https://jyx.jyu.fi/bitstream/handle/123456789/37868/GERUNDIV%20final%20draft.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

> can be reformulated with an extended participle

This is neither the Partizip I or Partizip II but the so called Gerundivum, or participium necessitatis. It's the third participle German has, and it's always built from the Partizip I. Never from the Partizip II.

So the answer is simple:

> … eine Maßnahme, die nicht **zu gestatten** ist. ← zu-Infinitiv

may be rephrased as

> … eine nicht **zu gestattende** Maßnahme. ← Gerundivum

Just as your book says. This isn't a matter of active or passive because the Gerundivum is **always** built from the Partizip I.